# Measure number of read operations in Sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any perf counter available to measure how many read operations are happening per second on Sql server database?
Table level reads counter will also work for me. Or is there any other way by which i can find out read count in the sql server database?

Comment: Tag which version you are using...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 and above

You can use `sp_monitor` stored procedure:

```
USE <db_name>
EXEC sp_monitor
```

find full documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188912.aspx

Comment: This do give some information. Writing a procedure and collecting data at definite intervals can give some useful info.

Answer (score 0):

Open the *perfmon.exe* tool, select Performance monitor, right click on the graph and select "Add counters...". From there search for the Logical disk or Physical disk groups of counters. You have all the read and write counters there.

Comment: Logical disk or Physical disk groups of counters shows read/write counters for the drives. I wanted to know the read counters for the SqlServer database

Comment: There are also some ways to get the read/write ratio for a database by using the DMVs. This link can help you http://sqlblog.com/blogs/louis_davidson/archive/2009/06/20/read-write-ratio-versus-read-write-ratio.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please check this 2 posts. May be it will help you.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3932406/Top-10-SQL-Server-Counters-for-Monitoring-SQL-Server-Performance.htm

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/automatically-capturing-sql-server-performance-metrics.html

Comment: These are performance metrics. I am already monitoring some of these counters. My requirement is for analytics purpose where i want to know the usage. For that i wanted to know how many times the table is getting queried.